# Tetrahedron angle question

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

[image]

A tetrahedron $ABCD$ has one edge $DB$ perpendicular to the base $ADC$ (see diagram). I want to show that $\cos\theta=\cos\beta\cos\alpha$. I can do this by dropping a perpendicular from $D$ to $AC$ then saying $\cos\theta=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{b}\times\frac{a}{c}$. That's fine. But does that mean I have showed $\cos\theta=\cos\beta\cos\alpha$ for *all* values of the angle $ADC$? Apologies if the answer is obvious; I only have school-level mathematics.

Comment: If $f$ and $e$ have same foot...

Comment: What does the "same foot" mean?

Comment: Goku solves this immediately without analytic geometry. Find him.

Comment: You dropped a perpendicular from D to AC at point X, so $\angle DXA = 90^o$. How about $\angle BXA$ ? I think @Bob Dobbs 's "same foot" is asking this question. Actually, it is not hard to prove $\angle BXA=90^o$, sometimes we may skip the proof and just put the statement.

Comment: @BobDobbs - who or what is Goku?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1092912/goku

Comment: @BobDobbs - your comments are not helpful

Comment: I am trying to understand too. I am not expert. What?!

Comment: @BobDobbs 1) I don't understand what your character "Goku" has to do with the solution of the problem. 2) You should keep **opinions** like "Synthetic geometry is really very hard subject" for yourself ; it is discouraging, not shared by most people here, and moreover, not applicable here which is a very simple problem.

Comment: @JeanMarie But, it is... It is not discouraging I am just praising that subject.

Comment: Synthetic proofs of geometric theorems make use of auxiliary constructs (such as helping lines) and concepts such as equality of sides or angles and similarity and congruence of triangles. Examples of such proofs can be found in the articles Butterfly theorem, Angle bisector theorem, Apollonius' theorem, British flag theorem, Ceva's theorem, Equal incircles theorem, Geometric mean theorem, Heron's formula, Isosceles triangle theorem, Law of cosines, and others that are linked to here.

Comment: It is simple for you I am not that clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ADC$ be in the $xy$ plane with $A$ at the origin and $AD$ along the $y$, then

$ \hat{AD} = (0, 1, 0) $

$ \hat{AC} = (\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha, 0 )$

$\hat{AB} = (0, \cos \beta, \sin \beta) $

The above are unit vectors.

The angle $\theta$ between $\hat{AB}$ and $\hat{AC}$ satisfies

$ \cos \theta = \dfrac{ \hat{AB} \cdot \hat{AC} }{\| \hat{AB} \| \| \hat{AC} \|} = \hat{AB} \cdot \hat{AC} = \cos \alpha \ \cos \beta $

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks to Pythagorean theorem":

$e^2+a^2=c^2$

$c^2+d^2=b^2$

$f^2=d^2+e^2$

........................+

$a^2+f^2=b^2$

That is $f$ is perpendicular to $AC$ and $e$ and $f$ have the same foot  on $AC$. Then your claim follows.

Comment: It was very difficult question. If you think hard enough 1+1=2 is not even simple.